# DataMapper not called on child FormType with 'inherit_data' => true (Symfony)

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

Is this always the case? I've searched the web and read the docs but am none the wiser. I did read that DataTransformers can't be applied when *inherit_data* is true, which also seems a shame. (What could be the reason?)

I have a FormType *'PermissionType'* which maps a *'Permission'*. *Permission* has, as do some other entities, a *creation/lastModification DateTime*. Having read [How to Reduce Code Duplication with "inherit_data"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/inherit_data_option.html) I naturally went on my way to implement the newly found good advice and created a *TimeTrackedType*.

This child form to PermissionType displays two DateTimeType fields and has `inherit_data` set to `true`. They are correctly rendered to the browser but they remain empty however I try to enter data into them. I started off by adding a DataMapper but the one of TimeTrackedType is not getting called. The DataMapper of its parent PermissionType however is, it being a child form itself, and that seems the only place where I can change the value of the DateTimeType fields of TimeTrackedType.

I do hope it's me doing something wrong here because it seems wrong having the inputs created in the child form but having to map to them in the parent class. Can anyone elaborate on this? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Here are the entities, first User:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {
    use HasSingleId, TimeTrackedEntityTrait, EntityCreatorTrait;
    //                 ^^^ This trait has two DateTime fields and that's it.
    // (...)
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Permission", mappedBy="user")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $permissions;
    // (...)
}
```

Then Permission:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PermissionRepository")
 */
class Permission {
use TimeTrackedEntityTrait, EntityCreatorTrait;

/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="permissions")
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Role", inversedBy="permissions")
 */
private $role;
// (...getters and setters...)
}
```

Lastly class Role:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\RoleRepository")
 */
class Role implements RoleInterface {
use HasSingleId, TimeTrackedEntityTrait, EntityCreatorTrait;

/**
 * @var type string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false, unique=true);
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var type ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Permission", mappedBy="role")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 */
private $permissions;
}
```

And now the FormTypes:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType {

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('username', TextType::class, [ 'attr' => [ 'size' => 10 ] ] )
            ->add('password', RepeatedType::class, [
                'type' => PasswordType::class, 
                'attr' => ['size' => 10 ], 
                'first_options' => [ 'label' => 'Password' ], 
                'second_options' => [ 'label' => 'Confirm' ] ]);
    $entity = $builder->getData();
    $admin = $entity->hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN');
    if($admin) {
        $builder->add('id', TextType::class, [ 'attr' => [ 'size' => 4 ] ]);
        $builder->add('isEnabled', CheckboxType::class, [ 'required' => false ]);
    }

    $builder->add('permissions', CollectionType::class, [
        'data_class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection',
        'mapped'=>true, 
        'prototype'=>true,
        'allow_add'=>true,
        'allow_delete'=>true,
        'entry_type' => PermissionType::class]);
    $builder->add('email', EmailType::class);
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'required' => true,
        'mapped' => true,
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\User'
    ]);
}
}
```

...and...

```
class PermissionType extends AbstractType implements DataMapperInterface {

public function mapDataToForms($permission, $forms) {
    $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);
    if($permission instanceof Permission && $permission) {
        $forms['role']->setData($permission->getRole()->getName());
        // These two statements get the job done, but not as was intended.
        $forms['created']->setData($permission->getCreated());
        $forms['lastModified']->setData($permission->getLastModified());
    }

}

public function mapFormsToData($forms, &$permission) {
    $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);
    if($permission instanceof Permission) {
        $permission->setCreated($forms['created']->getData());
        $permission->setLastModified($forms['lastModified']->getData());
    }
}


public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->setDataMapper($this);
    $builder->add('role', TextType::class, [ 'mapped' => true ]);
    $builder->add('timing', TimeTrackedEntityType::class, [ 
    'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Permission', 
    'inherit_data' => true, 'mapped'=>true ]);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Permission',
        'mapped'=>true,
        'compound'=>true,
    ));
}

public function getParent() {
    return FormType::class;
}

public function getName() { return 'PermissionType'; }

}
```

...and finally:

```
class TimeTrackedEntityType extends AbstractType implements DataMapperInterface {
// This is the method that doesn't get called
public function mapDataToForms($permission, $forms) {
    $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);
    $forms['created']->setData($permission->getCreated()->format("d/m/Y H:i:s"));
$forms['lastModified']->setData($permission->getLastModified()->format("d/m/Y H:i:s"));
}
public function mapFormsToData($forms, &$data) {
    $forms = iterator_to_array($forms);
    $data->setCreated($forms['created']->getData());
    $data->setLastModified($forms['lastModified']->getData());
}
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->setDataMapper($this);
    $builder->add('created', DateTimeType::class, [
         'format' => 'd/M/Y H:i:s', 
         'input' => 'datetime', 
         'widget' => 'single_text',
         'attr'=>['size'=>14, 'class'=>'right'],
         'mapped' => true ]);
    $builder->add('lastModified', DateTimeType::class, [ 
        'format' => 'd/M/Y H:i:s',
        'input' => 'datetime', 
        'widget' => 'single_text', 
        'attr'=>['size'=>14, 'class'=>'right'], 
        'mapped' => true ]);
}
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'mapped'=>true,
        'compound'=>true,
        'inherit_data' => true,
    ));
}

public function getName() { return 'TimeTrackedEntityType'; }
}
```

Comment: It would me more clear with a minimum of code :)

Comment: There you go. Have I done anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: I don't understand, does the `Permission` entity has a `timing` property with proper getter and setter ? because it looks like you use a trait to add the date fields.

Comment: Getters and setters are also in the trait, I use a lot of traits and it works like a charm, Doctrine annotations and all. If only they had working form elements to go with them. But no there is no "Timing" property, I had to give the child form a name, is that what's wrong here? In the cookbook example they don't add it to the containing form, I just assumed this was the way to add it.

Comment: No it just means you don't need that nested type. Just move the fields of `TimeTrackedEntityType` to `PermissionType` type directly.

Comment: You also don't need `'data_class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection',` nor `'mapped'=>true,` anywhere as it is the default

Comment: I have a lot of entities that use the TimeTrackedEntityTrait (or other traits) and was hoping I could separate the form fields for them as well, to be reused by all future forms of entities using that trait. And my current setup works, with the fields separated, the DataMapper of PermissionType does the work now. Why wouldn't the DataMapper be called on TimeTrackedEntityType while it does get called on PermissionType?

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The article does not use `DataMapper` at all.

Using a trait means the properties are part of the `PermissionEntity` object as normal, so instead of holding these properties like the other fields in the corresponding `PermissionType` form, they are nested in you sub form type `TimeTrackedEntityType`.

Then you just need to set `inherit_data` to `true` and the right `data_class` option if you need this sub form else where, and that's what you already do in `TimeTrackedEntityType`, since the sub form gets its parent form's data, so no need for `DataMapper`.

If you want to use one, it should only be with the parent form not its child, it is ignored as expected.